# Why are conversion results from proj.4 inaccurate?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, proj

I want to convert a Gauss-Kruger coordinate (EPSG::31467) into a WGS84 coordinate (EPSG::4326) using proj.4. The problem is that the output from proj.4 is very, very inaccurate.

Consider the Gauss-Kruger coordinate `(3509502, 5399989)`. I converted it with three different online converters. All results agreed to within four decimal places: `(48.7373, 9.1281)`. Moreover, I verified with Google Maps that `(48.7373, 9.1281)` is indeed the correct WGS84 coordinate (I know where it should be).

However, proj.4 converts the Gauss-Kruger coordinate into `(48.7384, 9.1292)`, more than 140 meters away from the correct solution. Why?

```
$ echo 3509502 5399989 | invproj +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs -f "%.4f"
9.1292  48.7384
```

The results are the same for version 4.8.0 and the newest version 4.9.3.

---

The solution (from @JGH):

```
$ echo 3509502 5399989 | cs2cs -f %.12f \
> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +no_defs \
> +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
9.128151599064  48.737368376923 51.846968705766
```

Comment: that sounds like a datum mixup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the fine [documentation](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/ManProj):

> The  proj  program  is  limited  to   converting  between  geographic
>   and  projection coordinates within one datum.

and

> Output  geographic  coordinates  will  be in DMS  and  precise  to 
>   0.001" with  trailing, zero-valued minute-second fields deleted.

The task you are trying is changing datum (Postdam 83 to WGS 84)

Answer (score 1):

The epsg file in my GDAL directory is using these definitions

```
# DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3
<31467> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

Gdaltransform utility http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html gives results which should make your happy

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:31467 -t_srs epsg:4326
3509502 5399989
9.12815159906357 48.737368376923 51.8469687057659
```

Because also gdaltransform is using proj4 I believe that problem in not in proj4 library itself but in the way you are using it. However, I can't say what is wrong or what is missing in your command if it is not the `+ellps=bessel` that is different in your proj string.

Comment: Because gdaltransform is more than a wrapper to proj4, and it allows changing datum